# Getting and setting all attributes for a file in Java

Tags: windows, java

I made an app (**Windows only**) with which you can create a backup of a folder/file locally or to a server. I'm done with the copy/restore process, but when it comes to restoring I have a small technical problem. If the file in originally hidden, then this is easy as you can call **Files.setAttribute(file.toPath(), "dos:hidden", true);** which will make the file hidden on client side after it is created/restored, but there are files like **desktop.ini** which aren't simply hidden but are **system file hidden** and the above code will only give it the hidden status, and not system file hidden (and maybe other files with other attributes as well).

There is also `Files.getAttribute()` but as the name suggests it only returns the attribute value for a single attribute, and not all of them to easily be able to do something like `Files.setAttributes(file.toPath(), Files.getAttributes(file.toPath()));`.

So my question is, is there a way to get a list will all the attributes a file has and then setting them in a more dynamically way and not having to call `Files.getAttribute();` / `Files.setAttribute();` for each of them line by line?

If unfortunately there isn't one, and you do have to set them line by line, can someone give me a list with all the attributes for **Windows OS**, like there is here for example the table of pattern symbols for [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)?

If you have to read/set them one by one, then I can make a template class which has a function that has a `File` as parameter to read the attributes and store them in a variable (maybe an **Array**), and a second function which has the same a `File` as parameter only that this time it will set the attributes read before. Doing it like this, I can even send this template class object over the socket with all the attributes to set them after the backup file is restored on client.

Comment: You mean like with getFileAttributeView and readAttributes? I’d try searching the web for something like “Java get windows file attributes” or something because there seems to be a fair amount of information available.

Comment: Tangential: Why write a platform-specific backup app in Java? Seems off.

Comment: @DaveNewton Just because Java *supports* multi-platform doesn't mean you should *only* use it for multi-platform purposes

Comment: [File Attributes List](http://www.foldermatch.com/helpfile/file-attributes-list.htm)

Comment: Can't you just use the `COPY_ATTRIBUTES` option when calling method [copy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...))?

Comment: @Jorn I didn’t say otherwise. It still doesn’t make sense in this case, even not knowing an MS platform. YMMV ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 7 you have platform specific attributes.
See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/DosFileAttributes.html